# Firefox: how to make browse buttons in forms accept urls?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

I often have to post files on different sites and some websites' forms only have a browse button to upload from your computer. If I have the file on another website, usually I have to go:

1. right click -> save image/link location as
2. browse -> select the file on my hard drive

I'm really hoping for a firefox extension to change that in:

1. right click -> copy image/link location
2. past and upload.

Eg. have firefox **take the file from the cache or download it silently** and upload it transparently.

I hope I won't have to write that myself...

Comment: I don't recall an existing extension, but if you paste a URL in the file upload box on Windows, Windows Explorer will try to download it quietly to a temp location and select that. Incidentally, it uses Internet Explorer to do that. I do that pretty often.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Do you mean Internet Explorer? I don't think that using IE is going to be an option for me but it's good to know...

Comment: You wouldn't be using IE. If you paste a URL into the path box in the file selection popup, Windows will download the file in the background (may take ~10 seconds). I *believe* it uses IE in the background, but whatever it uses you never see it.

Comment: So you're saying ff on windows has this feature already thanks to Windows allowing http(s) paths in a standard file open dialog. Ok, that's cool. I just verified to be sure, on debian linux with gnome it definitely doesn't work.

Comment: It still would be nice to have a self-contained solution within FF (have you considered suggesting it?).

Comment: No, in general firefox has a policy of minimal core features with extensions. On top of that there's so many things I would have to suggest to them... When I right-click on an image and click save image, it re-downloads it rather than copy it from the cache... now that's smart. There are quite a few basic things I think don't work like they should, but I don't really have the time to get into ff development to look into all of them. On linux about every program you use regularly barfs on you and needs work done, so it becomes endless... If even only I could get decent firmware so...

Comment: ... my wifi wouldn't crash my system.